# Javascript function with name from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How to generate javascript function with the name taken from ViewBag? I'm trying the below

```
@{ (ViewBag.ModuleId + "DatePickerStartDateChange = function() {console.log('asdf');};");}
```

and hoping that it will emit javascript in the html output as

```
xxxxxxDatePickerStartDateChange = function() {alert("asdf");};
```

Comment: You really shouldn't couple server & client code that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no idea why on earth you would need to do that, but here's the correct syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @(ViewBag.ModuleId)DatePickerStartDateChange = function() {
        console.log('asdf');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I'm create a generic PartialView which will be used more than once in my View hence, in order for the javascript to work, i need to create saperate function name for each PartialView. Does that make sense? or there are better way of doing it?

Comment: No, this doesn't make any sense.